# How to locate the minimum pressure as well longitude and latitude from nc file

Tags: parameters

I want to locate the minimum pressure as well longitude and latitude from an nc wrfout file...

I tried this but it did not work. I am new to wrf and am not sure of the script to use to get the minimum value of MSLP and the latitude and longitude corresponding to it.

```
print(np.where(n == msl.min()))
```